# OData CSV Serialization for Navigation Properties

Tags: csv, serialization, text, odata

I'm trying to develop an OData serializer so that my OData REST API's return comma separated values instead of JSON.

Karata Liu has written an excellent article [[Tutorial & Sample] ODataLib Custom Payload Format](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2015/01/05/tutorial-sample-odatalib-custom-payload-format/)  that describes how to do this.

Liu's example does exactly what I want for all of the entity properties that I need to return in the response message, except for navigation properties. For navigation properties, I would like to just list out their property values separated by commas along with the main entity's properties.

I'm not certain, but I think my problem is with my override of Microsoft's ODataOutputContext method CreateODataFeedWriter(IEdmEntitySetBase entitySet, IEdmEntityType entityType):

```
internal sealed class CsvOutputContext : ODataOutputContext
{
    private Stream stream;

    public CsvOutputContext(
        ODataFormat format,
        ODataMessageWriterSettings settings,
        ODataMessageInfo messageInfo,
        bool synchronous)
        : base(format, settings, messageInfo.IsResponse, synchronous, messageInfo.Model, messageInfo.UrlResolver)
    {
        this.stream = messageInfo.GetMessageStream();
        this.Writer = new StreamWriter(this.stream);
    }

    public TextWriter Writer { get; private set; }

    public override ODataWriter CreateODataEntryWriter(IEdmNavigationSource navigationSource,
        IEdmEntityType entityType)
    {
        return new CsvWriter(this, entityType);
    }

    public override ODataWriter CreateODataFeedWriter(IEdmEntitySetBase entitySet, IEdmEntityType entityType)
    {
        return new CsvWriter(this, entityType);
    }
```

I'm not doing anything with the entitySet argument and I think I need to connect it to my CSVWriter class (which derives from Microsoft's ODataWriter class). The method argument is obviously there for some reason, but I'm not sure how to use it.

My CSVWriter class looks like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.OData.Core;
using Microsoft.OData.Edm;

namespace Hach.Fusion.FOART.Api.CsvMediaType
{
    internal class CsvWriter : ODataWriter
    {
        private CsvOutputContext context;
        private List<string> headers;

        public CsvWriter(CsvOutputContext context, IEdmEntityType entityType)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.WriteHeader(entityType);
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            this.context.Flush();
        }

        public override void WriteEnd()
        {
        }

        public override void WriteStart(ODataFeed feed)
        {
        }

        public override void WriteStart(ODataEntry entry)
        {
            this.WriteEntry(entry);
        }

        private void WriteHeader(IEdmEntityType entityType)
        {
            this.headers = entityType.Properties().Where(p => p.Type.IsPrimitive()).Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
            foreach (var header in this.headers)
            {
                this.context.Writer.Write("{0},", header);
            }

            this.context.Writer.WriteLine();
        }


        private void WriteEntry(ODataEntry entry)
        {
            foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
            {
                //var property = entry.Properties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == header);
                if (property != null)
                {
                    this.context.Writer.Write(property.Value);
                }

                this.context.Writer.Write(",");
            }

            //foreach (var header in this.headers)
            //{
            //    var property = entry.Properties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == header);
            //    if (property != null)
            //    {
            //        this.context.Writer.Write(property.Value);
            //    }

            //    this.context.Writer.Write(",");
            //}

            this.context.Writer.WriteLine();
        }

        #region not implemented
        public override void WriteEntityReferenceLink(ODataEntityReferenceLink entityReferenceLink)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteStart(ODataNavigationLink navigationLink)
        {

        }
        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task FlushAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteEndAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteEntityReferenceLinkAsync(ODataEntityReferenceLink entityReferenceLink)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteStartAsync(ODataNavigationLink navigationLink)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteStartAsync(ODataEntry entry)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteStartAsync(ODataFeed feed)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        #endregion
```

The WriteStart(ODataNavigationLink navigationLink) method is called, but there is nothing in the navigationLink argument that provides a value that I can serialize. Nor is there a reference to the entity being serialized. There is the navigation property name, but that's it.

I'm missing something on this. For the non-navigation properties this seems straight forward (although that may be because Liu's article shows the way).